# Using python code to remove duplicate files from a directory and subdirectory

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through directories and subdirectories to find duplicate files but issue encountered here is script is giving some errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fileDupchknew.py", line 29, in <module>
    dup_fileremove(dirname)
  File "./fileDupchknew.py", line 26, in dup_fileremove
    os.remove(filepath)
  OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/tmp/rishabh-test/new-test'
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import hashlib
import sys


dirname = sys.argv[1] os.chdir(dirname)

 def dup_fileremove(dir):
    duplicate = set()
    os.chdir(dir)
    path=os.getcwd()
    print ("The dir is: ", path)
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        filehash = None
        filepath=os.path.join(dir, filename)
        print("Current file path is: ", filepath)
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            dup_fileremove(filepath)
        elif os.path.isfile(filepath):
            filehash =hashlib.md5(file(filepath).read()).hexdigest()
        if filehash not in duplicate:
            duplicate.add(filehash)
        else:
            os.remove(filepath)
            print("removed : ", filepath)

dup_fileremove(dirname)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the stack trace. But what was the actual error message? That should appear on the line just below the stack trace.

Comment: Is `def dup_fileremove(dir):` commented out in your original code, or is that a transcription error from writing this post?

Comment: What's up with your multiple import statements being all on one line?

Comment: My bad complete stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fileDupchknew.py", line 28, in <module>
    dup_fileremove(dirname)
  File "./fileDupchknew.py", line 25, in dup_fileremove
    os.remove(filepath)
OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/tmp/rishabh-test/new-test'

Comment: I also suspect transcription errors, because it's not easy for the error to be on line 29 when there are only 24 lines in the script. :)

Comment: BTW, `dir` is **not** a good variable name since it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: `os.remove` raises an OSError when the thing you're trying to delete is a folder. Try using `rmdir` for folders instead.

Comment: Do you really want to delete directories ?

Comment: No i don't want to delete directories

Comment: You should read the error message, it's often quite informative. Your error message says "Is a directory" and complains on `os.remove(filepath)`. This should be a hint that maybe you can't do `os.remove(filepath)` if it is a directory? Then you check the documentation and it says that if `filepath` is a directory this exception is raised.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm pretty sure that the OP only wants to remove files, so the fact that `os.remove` raises an `OSError` when you attempt to delete directories has probably been a *very* good thing in this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not want to delete directories (as can be seen from comments in question) -

> No i don't want to delete directories

If the above is the case, then your issue occurs because you are not creating filehash for the directories. Because when you do not create a filehash for the directory, you get the filehash as `None` , and for the first directory, `None` is not present in the `duplicates` set , so it adds `None` to the set. From next directory onwards, it sees that `None` is already present in the `set()` , hence it tries to use `os.remove()` on it causing the issue.

A simple fix would be to check whether `filehash` is `None` or not , before trying to remove as well as before adding to set. Example -

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os 
import hashlib
import sys


dirname = sys.argv[1] 
os.chdir(dirname)

 def dup_fileremove(dir):
    duplicate = set()
    os.chdir(dir)
    path=os.getcwd()
    print ("The dir is: ", path)
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        filehash = None
        filepath=os.path.join(dir, filename)
        print("Current file path is: ", filepath)
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            dup_fileremove(filepath)
        elif os.path.isfile(filepath):
            filehash =hashlib.md5(file(filepath).read()).hexdigest()
        if filehash is not None and filehash not in duplicate:
            duplicate.add(filehash)
        elif filehash is not None:
            os.remove(filepath)
            print("removed : ", filepath)

dup_fileremove(dirname)
```

Comment: its working as expected. Really want to thank you over this.

Comment: I am glad I could be helpful :) .

Comment: In addition to this i also updated my script to check duplication between various sub directories eg. if a file is in a-test directory and same file is in b-test directory within /tmp directory then it will remove one file and hence redundancy is removed. This is achieved by declaring set outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually lucky you got that error message, otherwise your code would have deleted directories!

The problem is that after control returns from the recursive call to

`dup_fileremove(filepath)`

it then continues on to

`if filehash not in duplicate:`

You don't want that!

A simple way to fix it is to put a `continue` statement after `dup_fileremove(filepath)`.

But a much better fix is to indent the `if filehash not in duplicate:` stuff so that it's aligned with the `filehash = hashlib.md5(file(filepath).read()).hexdigest()` line.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os 
import hashlib
import sys

def dup_fileremove(dirname):
    duplicate = set()
    os.chdir(dirname)
    path=os.getcwd()
    print ("The dirname is: ", path)
    for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
        filehash = None
        filepath=os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        print("Current file path is: ", filepath)
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            dup_fileremove(filepath)
        elif os.path.isfile(filepath):
            filehash =hashlib.md5(file(filepath).read()).hexdigest()
            if filehash not in duplicate:
                duplicate.add(filehash)
            else:
                os.remove(filepath)
                print("removed : ", filepath)

dirname = sys.argv[1] 
os.chdir(dirname)

dup_fileremove(dirname)
```

I haven't tested this modified version of your code. It *looks* ok, but I make no guarantees. :)

BTW, it is recommended to not use the `file()` class directly to open files. In Python 3, `file()` no longer exists, but even in Python the docs have recommended the use of the `open()` function since at least Python 2.5, if not earlier.